# Powerapps network problem - only works on company network after using own internet connection

Tags: powerapps

The company where I work uses its own network, we also have internet.
Few days ago some of the employees cannot reach powerapps apps.
We found a solution: disconnect laptop from companys network, connect to other internet (eg. mobile), run the app. Then reconnect the comapany network, and the powerapps app works.

This solution works with laptops but most of the employees work on PC.

What should we do, to make the apps work, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have your org's IT people whitelist the PowerPlatform domains and IP addresses found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/online-requirements).